# How to read double-quoted string values using terraform csvdecode?

Tags: csv, terraform

I have a CSV file that contains the following content:

```
id,value
123,{"M":{"name_1":{"S":"value_1"}, "name_2":{"S":"value_2"}}}
```

I'm trying to read this CSV file and create records in DynamoDB the following way:

```
locals {
  custom_data = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/../custom_data.csv"))
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "custom_table_item" {
  for_each = {for row in local.custom_data : row.id => row}

  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.custom_table.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.custom_table.hash_key

  item = jsonencode({
    "id" : { "S" : each.value.id },
    "value" : jsondecode(each.value.value)
  })

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [item]
  }
}
```

However, this code doesn't work and I can't find any example on how to read the double-quoted values from the CSV file in a way that `jsondecode` can create the appropriate JSON structure.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanitize your csv file:

```
id,value
123,"{""M"":{""name_1"":{""S"":""value_1""}, ""name_2"":{""S"":""value_2""}}}"
```

then:

```bash
$ terraform-repl
> csvdecode(file("${path.module}/custom_data.csv"))
tolist([
  {
    "id" = "123"
    "value" = "{\"M\":{\"name_1\":{\"S\":\"value_1\"}, \"name_2\":{\"S\":\"value_2\"}}}"
  },
])

> jsondecode(csvdecode(file("${path.module}/custom_data.csv"))[0].value)
{
  "M" = {
    "name_1" = {
      "S" = "value_1"
    }
    "name_2" = {
      "S" = "value_2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The document you showed here isn't really a CSV document in the usual sense that Terraform's function is intended to parse, which is the format defined in [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). Your second "field" seems to be a JSON document with its own fields inside, including commas, meaning that `csvdecode` will misunderstand what this document is intended to mean.

Instead, I'd consider this to be a custom format and so parse it using simpler primitives:

```
locals {
  custom_data_raw = file("${path.module}/../custom_data.csv")
  custom_data_lines = slice([
    for chunk in split("\n", local.custom_data_raw) : chomp(chunk)
  ], 1, length(local.custom_data_raw))
  custom_data_fields = [
    for line in local.custom_data_lines : regex("^(?P<id>[^,]),(?P<values>.*)$", line)
  ]
  custom_data = {
    for fields in local.custom_data_fields :
    fields.id => jsondecode(fields.value)
  }
}
```

The above uses a mixture of different Terraform functions to split the file contents into smaller tokens:

- [`split`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split) to split the whole content into individual lines (with [`chomp`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/chomp) to deal with the possibility of Windows-style line endings, which would be `\r\n` instead of just `\n` and so need extra stripping afterwards.)
- [`slice`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/slice) to discard the first line, which is the "header" row.
- [`regex`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex) to separate the "id" and "values" fields in a way that ignores the extra commas and quotes in the "values" field.
- Then finally [`jsondecode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsondecode) to replace the "values" string with the object it's describing using JSON syntax.

I split this over multiple steps to make it easier to see the results of the intermediate steps, but you should be able to combine at least some of these steps together into larger expressions if you prefer.

After all of this, `local.custom_data` should be a data structure you can use with `for_each`, shaped like this:

```
{
  "123" = {
    "M" = {
      "name_1" = {
        "S" = "value_1"
      }
      "name_2" = {
        "S" = "value_2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "custom_table_item" {
  for_each = local.custom_data

  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.custom_table.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.custom_table.hash_key

  item = jsonencode({
    "id" : { "S" : each.key },
    "value" : each.values
  })

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [item]
  }
}
```

---

If you *do* want to treat this as a regular CSV document and use `csvdecode` then you will need to first change the encoding of the "value" fields to escape the quotes and commas, which means:

- Writing the entire JSON string in the second argument in quotes `"`, as described in RFC 4180 section 2 item 6.
- Writing the literal quotes inside your JSON document as escaped by doubling (`""` instead of just `"`), as described in RFC 4180 section 2 item 7.

If would be possible in principle to perform that transformation using Terraform itself, but it would be largely the same as the lower-level parsing I showed above to first tokenize the id and value fields separately, so I wouldn't take this option unless I could change whatever system is generating the original document to produce valid CSV data itself, so that Terraform can then rely only on `csvdecode`.

Comment: Not sure really, if you look at this RFC bullet item the CSV I'm using is in accordance: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#:~:text=If%20double%2Dquotes%20are%20used%20to%20enclose%20fields

Comment: Also, take a look here for line breaks: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#:~:text=Fields%20containing%20line%20breaks

Comment: Point six says "Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes". Your "value" field contains both double quotes and commas but is not enclosed in double quotes, so this input is non-conforming.

Comment: You're right, I already had in mind the solution using "" when I said that :/